# Sign of function with c.d.f. and p.d.f. of normal distribution

Tags: proof-writing, normal-distribution

I have the following function:

$\begin{align*}
 f(Z)=&Z\Phi\big(Z\big)\big(2\Phi\big(Z\big)^2-3\Phi\big(Z\big)+1\big)\phi\big(Z\big)\\
 &+\big( 2\Phi\big(Z\big)^2-2\Phi\big(Z\big)+1\big)\phi\big(Z\big)^2 
 \end{align*}$

where $\Phi$ is the c.d.f. of a standard normal variable, and $\phi$ the p.d.f. of a standard normal variable. The function looks like this:

[image]

I want to formally prove that $f(Z)\geq 0$, I have been trying to factorize the function into factors and then look at the sign of each individual factor. But I havent been able to do any progress.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that first term actually multiplied by $Z$, or is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, let me fix it so it looks better